# Nestjs: Access control based on the organization of a user

Tags: nestjs, access-control, role-based-access-control, nestjs-passport

I am writing my first API with NestJS and I am looking for a smart way of managing access to resources. I have the following simplified structure:

- organization:

  - users
  - products
- users:

  - email
  - organization
- products:

  - organization
  - more data

I use Passport JWT and Local strategies. But I want to make sure only users from inside the organization can update and create products for that organization.

I have looked at [nest-access-control](https://github.com/nestjsx/nest-access-control) but can't figure out if it can be used for this.

Comment: have you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a third table called 'memberOrganization', with the following columns:

- membersOrganization

  - idMembersOrganization
  - idUser
  - idOrganization
  - idPermission

and a fourth table:

- permissions

  - idPermission
  - permission

That way you could check if that user is a member of that organization and what permissions they have (using leftJoins). Depending on permission, you allow the creation of such products.

Holpe this helps.